# How to Mock a list transformation using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq, automapper

I am using AutoMapper and have a definition of mapping engine as

```
private readonly IMappingEngine _mappingEngine;
```

I initialize it via constructor injection and use in the code as below

```
var product=//Get a single product
var productModel = _mappingEngine.Map<ProductModel>(product);
```

The above works perfectly. I now need to map a list of `Product` to list of `ProductModel` The following works in the controller action

```
var entities =//Get list of products
var model = entities.Select(e => _mappingEngine.Map<ProductModel>(e));
```

The above LINQ code uses foreach and converts each `Product` to a `ProductModel` Now I need to unit test the above code but unable to use Moq to mock the LINQ  statement above

I've tried the following

```
var mapper = new Mock<IMappingEngine>();
mapper.Setup(m => m.Map<ProductModel>(product)).Returns(ProductModel);
```

The above mapper setup works for single object mapping. How can we setup the above using a list of products

So, I want to be able to setup a list of `Product` like this:

```
var productList=new List<Product>{new Product{Id=1,name="product 1"},
                                  new Product{Id=2,name="product 2"}};
```

and define a mocking that will return a list of `ProductModel` like this:

```
var productModelList=new List<ProductModel>{new ProductModel{Id=1,name="product 1"},
                                            new ProductModel{Id=2,name="product 2"}};
```

when my test calls the controller (which uses the mock `IMappingEngine` to transform the list)

```
var model = entities.Select(e => _mappingEngine.Map<ProductModel>(e));
```

So, when writing Moq unit tests how can we setup the above so that `_mappingEngine.Map` that takes `productList` as input and returns `productModelList`?

Comment: I am not clear what you want here?

Comment: @Liam apologies for not being clearer.  I have added some explanation of the issue. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First up, do you *really* need to mock the mapping from `Product` to `ProductModel`, or would it be just as valid to create an instance of `IMappingEngine` and supply it to your controller, rather than a `Mock.Object`.

Something as simple adding the mapping in your test setup:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Product, ProductModel>();
```

and clearing the mapping in your test teardown:

```
Mapper.Reset();
```

Would allow you to just supply `Mapper.Engine` to controllers constructor in your test.  Obviously it depends on your approach to testing, but for something like AutoMapper which is well used and reliable, with little time overhead, this may well be a valid approach.

Assuming you do want to mock the mapping, you can use a callback to return a different item for each call, doing something like this:

```
// Create a list of the mapped values you're expecting
var productModels = new List<ProductModel> {
    new ProductModel { Id=11,name="eleven"},
    new ProductModel { Id=12,name="twelve"},
    new ProductModel { Id=13,name="thirteen"}
};

// Mock the IMappingEngine
var engine = new Mock<IMappingEngine>();

// Create a variable to count the calls
var calls=0;

// Mock ALL calls to map, where the destination is ProductModel
// and source is Product
engine.Setup(m => m.Map<ProductModel>(It.IsAny<Product>()))
      .Returns(()=>productModels[calls]) // Return next productModel
      .Callback(()=>calls++)   // Increment counter to point to next model
```

You should notice, that the mock `Setup` is mocking individual mappings, not mapping a list of `Product` to a list of `ProductModel`.  That's because your call to `entities.Select(e => _mappingEngine.Map<ProductModel>(e))` is looping through your list an item at a time, not asking the mapping engine (or your mock) to map the list in one go...

If you need to be more precise in your mocking, then it's also possible to extend the `Callback` to verify that the expected `Product` is being mapped.  You probably won't want to do this every time, but it can be useful in some circumstances.  So, you could do something like:

```
// Declare a list of expected products to map from
var products = new List<Product> { 
    new Product {Id=1, name="One"},
    new Product {Id=2, name="Two"},
    new Product {Id=3, name="Three"}
};


engine.Setup(m => m.Map<ProductModel>(It.IsAny<Product>()))
      .Returns(() => productModels[calls])
      .Callback<Product>(x => {Assert.AreEqual(x.Id, products[calls].Id); calls++;});
```

Comment: Thanks for this "do you really need to mock", all I needed. :)